# How to Change facebook cover image with Php and Curl http request

Tags: php, facebook, curl, httprequest

I'm having issues with facebook and PHP.

I'm trying to change the cover photo of my facebook page when i refresh it. Facebook documentation isn't clear at all, i just understood that it's not possible to do it with the php API yet.

I found that on fb dvpers :

"Also, you can set your Page's cover photo by issuing an HTTP POST request:

curl -F "cover=1232343" -F "offset_y=30" -F "no_feed_story=false" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?access_token__" "

i can get my token access  through browser with an url like :

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=URL&scope=publish_stream

but i don't understand well how to use curl to change the cover photo of my app. If anyone could help it would be awesome. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use publish_stream? you don´t need that permission. also, you need a page access token for this. the facebook docs are very clear about that.

try it with the php sdk (untested):

```
$response = $facebook->api('/PAGE-ID', 'POST', array(
    'access_token' => $page_access_token,
    'cover' => 'PICTURE-ID'
));
```